# Nokogiri- how do I parse through this wikipedia table if it doesn't have unique TR names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

here is what I have so far...The issue is that it is producing a JSON file that looks like (see below). My problem is that when I inspect the code on the page, I don't see anything unique to the css selectors. They all are simply tr td a. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

sammiches = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sandwiches"))

class Scraper

def initialize
 @url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sandwiches"
 @nodes = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))

end

def summary(filename)

 sammich_data = @nodes

 sammiches = sammich_data.css('div.mw-content-ltr table.wikitable tr') 


 sammich_hashes = sammiches.map {|x| 
   name = x.css('td a').text
   image = x.css('td a.image').text
   country = x.css('td a').text
   description = x.css('td a').text

 {
  :name => name,
  :image => image,
  :country => country,
  :description => description,
  }
    }

File.open("public/#{filename}","w") do |f|
 f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(sammich_hashes))
 end   
 end

 sammy = Scraper.new
 puts sammy.summary('listy')
 end
```

Json file output partial

```
[
{
"name": "",
"image": "",
"country": "",
"description": ""
},
{
"name": "BaconUnited Kingdomketchupbrown sauce",
"image": "",
"country": "BaconUnited Kingdomketchupbrown sauce",
"description": "BaconUnited Kingdomketchupbrown sauce"
},
{
"name": "Bacon, egg and cheesebreakfast sandwich",
"image": "",
"country": "Bacon, egg and cheesebreakfast sandwich",
"description": "Bacon, egg and cheesebreakfast sandwich"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the td index:

```
name = x.at('td[1]').text
country = x.at('td[3]').text
```

You might want to remove the citations first:

```
sammich_data.search('sup').remove
```

Comment: I was so close! Thanks so much. I am a bit confused on what you mean by citations though?

Comment: @DynastySS: The superscripted "[4]" on Bánh mì for example.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than parse Wikipedia's HTML, take advantage of [their API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page), which will give you the data in XML, or JSON or other formats. It's cleaner and more reusable.

You can even get HTML used to render a page without all the borders and boxes.

Comment: It's a good idea but I've noticed in the past that you won't always get the most up to date data from the API

Comment: I've never compared the output of the direct URL vs. the API. The things I looked up hadn't changed so I had no way to tell or suspect there could be a problem with staleness. Since the API can return the HTML of different sections of a page, it seems to me they'd be using their own API as building blocks for their own pages so that wouldn't be an issue.